# Update statement in asp.net encountered with logic error?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, updates

I'm developing a project where user can can edit/update their profile, but somehow I found myself in trouble when try to update the data into Access Database. The only funniest thing is, ONLY profile picture is updated/change in database, but none for password, firstname, lastname, etc. The rest still the same. I hope someone can help me in this case, thanks in advance!

The Page Load:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
    DropDownList1.DataBind()
End If
    LinkButtonCancel.Visible = False
    FileuploadProfPic.Visible = False
    TextBoxCfrmPassword.Visible = False
    ButtonUpdateProf.Visible = False
    TextBoxImage.Visible = False
    LabelUpload.Visible = False
    LabelCfnPss.Visible = False

    TextBoxUsername.Enabled = False
    TextBoxPassword.Enabled = False
    TextBoxFirstName.Enabled = False
    TextBoxLastName.Enabled = False
    TextBoxEmail.Enabled = False
    TextBoxHPN.Enabled = False

    TextBoxUsername.ReadOnly = True
    TextBoxPassword.ReadOnly = True
    TextBoxFirstName.ReadOnly = True
    TextBoxLastName.ReadOnly = True
    TextBoxEmail.ReadOnly = True
    TextBoxHPN.ReadOnly = True

    UserData = Me.Data()
    TextBoxUsername.Text = UserData.Username
    TextBoxFirstName.Text = UserData.FirstName
    TextBoxLastName.Text = UserData.LastName
    TextBoxHPN.Text = UserData.MobileNumber
    TextBoxEmail.Text = UserData.Email
    ProfilePic.ImageUrl = UserData.ProfilePic
    TextBoxImage.Text = UserData.ProfilePic
    TextBoxPassword.Text = UserData.Password
```

The Data Function to call the data from database:

```
    Dim dvLogin As DataView = CType(AccessDataSourceProfile.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
    dvLogin.RowFilter = "Username = '" & DropDownList1.SelectedValue & "'"

    Dim Dt As New UserLogin

    Dt.Username = dvLogin(0)("Username").ToString
    Dt.Password = dvLogin(0)("Password").ToString
    Dt.FirstName = dvLogin(0)("FirstName").ToString
    Dt.LastName = dvLogin(0)("LastName").ToString
    Dt.MobileNumber = dvLogin(0)("MobileNumber").ToString
    Dt.Email = dvLogin(0)("Email").ToString
    Dt.ProfilePic = dvLogin(0)("ProfilePic").ToString

    Return Dt
```

The Update Button:

```
strConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("Product.mdb") & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=;"

objConn.ConnectionString = strConnString
objConn.Open()

Dim savePath As String = "C:\Users\AdananLong\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\E-Commerce\E-Commerce\"
If (FileuploadProfPic.HasFile) Then
    Dim files As String = FileuploadProfPic.FileName

    savePath += files

    FileuploadProfPic.SaveAs(savePath)

    TextBoxImage.Text = files

    Try
        objCmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Member SET [Password] = @password, FirstName = @firstname, LastName = @lastname, MobileNumber = @mobilenumber, Email = @email, ProfilePic = @profilepic WHERE Username = @username", objConn)

        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPassword.Text)
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", TextBoxFirstName.Text)
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", TextBoxLastName.Text)
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobilenumber", TextBoxHPN.Text)
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text)
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profilepic", TextBoxImage.Text)
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBoxUsername.Text)


        objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        DropDownList1.DataBind()
        Me.LabelWarning.Visible = True
        Me.LabelWarning.Text = "Update Sucessful."


    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.LabelWarning.Visible = True
        Me.LabelWarning.Text = "Cannot Update : Error (" & ex.Message & ")"
    End Try
Else
    Try
        objCmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Member SET [Password] = @password, FirstName = @firstname, LastName = @lastname, MobileNumber = @mobilenumber, Email = @email, ProfilePic = @profilepic WHERE Username = @username", objConn)

        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPassword.Text)
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", TextBoxFirstName.Text)
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", TextBoxLastName.Text)
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobilenumber", TextBoxHPN.Text)
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text)
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profilepic", TextBoxImage.Text)
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBoxUsername.Text)


        objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        DropDownList1.DataBind()
        Me.LabelWarning.Visible = True
        Me.LabelWarning.Text = "Update Sucessful."

    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.LabelWarning.Visible = True
        Me.LabelWarning.Text = "Cannot Update : Error (" & ex.Message & ")"
    End Try
End If

objConn.Close()
objConn = Nothing
```

Comment: This seems to be a well know effect of forgetting to test for PostBacks in the Page_Load code. Could you show it?

Comment: In pageload event, i only use dropdownlist to bind and show the data. Im not quite good at this. "If Not Page.IsPostBack Then DropDownlist1.Databind() End If"

Comment: Where is the code that initializes the textbox controls? The same textboxes used in the update to pass a value for the parameters?

Comment: Please refer to the edited question. Sorry if Im not giving enough informations though. I thought there is a problem in my update statement or something.

Comment: Exactly what I said in my answer. The code that initializes the TextBoxes should be protected by the _If Not IsPostBack Then_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a well know effect of forgetting to test for postbacks in the Page_Load code.
Every time your user triggers an event to be handled on the server (runat="server" and/or AutoPostBack="true" )  then the **Page.Load** event of your page is called BEFORE calling the event handler activated by the user action.  See [ASP.NET Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227435(v=vs.100).aspx)

This means that in your **Page.Load** code you should be careful to not reload the page controls with values from the database otherwise, when the event handler is started, you have the controls filled with the original values extracted in the Page.Load event.

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        .....
        ' code to load the controls with values from database 

        UserData = Me.Data()
        TextBoxUsername.Text = UserData.Username
        TextBoxFirstName.Text = UserData.FirstName
        TextBoxLastName.Text = UserData.LastName
        TextBoxHPN.Text = UserData.MobileNumber
        TextBoxEmail.Text = UserData.Email
        ProfilePic.ImageUrl = UserData.ProfilePic
        TextBoxImage.Text = UserData.ProfilePic
        TextBoxPassword.Text = UserData.Password

    End If
End Sub
```